# Headset disappeared when mode is changed on sound settings

Tags: usb, sound, headset

I have a Steelseries headset that uses USB. On the sound settings, I just changed the mode to audio output and it disappeared from the list of outputs. How can I get it back?

Comment: Does restarting the computer make it reappear? And then it again disappears when you change the mode again?